# Method injection dagger2 null exception when asking for the dependency

Tags: android, dagger-2

Hi i'm trying to use method injection with dagger 2 and im getting null pointer exception when using the injected dependency i tried removing the @provide annotation and extracted the DialogManger in separate module here

```
@Module
```

public class DialogManagerModule {

```
Context context;

public DialogManagerModule(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Provides
DialogManager provideDialogManager(Context context){
    return new DialogManager(context);
}

@Provides
ProgressDialogInteractor provideProgressDialogInteractor(){
    return new ProgressDialog();
}

@Provides
Context provideContext(){
    return context;
}
```

}

```
public class DialogManager {

Context context;

ProgressDialogInteractor progressDialog;

@Inject
public void setProgressDialog(ProgressDialogInteractor progressDialog) {
    this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
}

public DialogManager(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void showDatePickerDialog(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     new DatePickerDialog(
            context
             , listener
             , calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
             , calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
             , calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
             .show();
}

public void showProgressDialog(@Nullable String progressText){

    progressDialog
           /* .setText(progressText)
            .showText()*/
            .show();

}
```

}

and here how i called the component

```
component =((App) getActivity().getApplication()).getComponent()
            .newPersonalInfoFragmentComponent(new PersonalInfoFragmentModule(this), new DialogManagerModule(getContext()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your context like that in ContextModule class, and you have to provide all objects that you use in provide methods.

```
@Singleton
@Module
public abstract class ContextModule {

    @Binds
    abstract Context provideContext(Application application);
}
```